# Take a "nanmean" in xarray

Tags: python, numpy, nan, python-xarray

I know that I can use the numpy nanmean function to take the mean of a numpy array, while ignoring NaN values. Is there an analogous way to accomplish this with xarray? I will give an example...

```
numpy_array=[1,2,3,4,float('nan'),5]

np.mean(numpy_array)
> NaN

np.nanmean(numpy_array)
> 3.0
```

In xarray, I can do

```
xarray_example.mean(dim='dimension')
```

How can I change this to a nanmean?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can supply `skipna=True`. Straight from the documentation : http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.mean.html

Comment: Thank you, Grayrigel! I don't know why I missed this when I looked at the docs, but I appreciate you pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [xarray docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.mean.html) for the mean function, you can set the **skipna** parameter as **True** (it will skip missing float values by default). So:

```
xarray_example.mean(dim='dimension', skipna=True)
```